# Golang: sqlx StructScan mapping db column to struct

Tags: go

i have my model struct like the below :

```
type Detail struct {
 Product
 Stocks
}
type Product struct {
 Name        string         `db:"name"`
 Id          int            `db:"id"`
}
type  Stocks { 
 Name        string         `db:"name"`
 Price       float          `db:"price"`
 Type        string         `db:"type"`
}
```

i would have a query to join the above tables like the below :

```
query, args, err := sqlx.In("select p.name , s.price from Product   p,Stocks s where p.name=s.name and type IN (?)",typecodes)
query = s.Cmd.Db.Rebind(query)
var rows *sqlx.Rows
rows, err = s.Cmd.Db.Queryx(query, args...)

for rows.Next() {
          var p model.Detail
          err = rows.StructScan(&p)
}
```

Would like to know when i do **rows.StructScan(&p)** will the Product structure Name field be populated or will there be any ambuigity found for the same since Stocks also have a Name field ?

Currently i am not getting any result for the above.But when i comment the Name field in the Stocks struct, i am getting the data.

Let me know what i am missing here.

Comment: For ambiguous fields you're best annotating them with a prefix of their struct name, e.g. `product_name`, `stock_name`, then alias them appropriately in your SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks Martin.It worked fine:)

Comment: @MartinGallagher Post that as an answer.

Comment: No problem - done!

Answer (score 3):

For ambiguous fields you're best annotating them with a prefix of their struct name, e.g. `product_name`, `stock_name`, then alias them appropriately in your SQL statement.

I.e.

```
type Detail struct {
 Product
 Stocks
}

type Product struct {
 Name        string         `db:"product_name"`
 Id          int            `db:"id"`
}

type  Stocks { 
 Name        string         `db:"stock_name"`
 Price       float          `db:"price"`
 Type        string         `db:"type"`
}
```

And in your SQL:

```sql
SELECT p.name AS product_name, s.name AS stock_name, ... FROM Product p, Stocks s WHERE ...
```